# missing background in outlook

Tags: background, outlook

Hi I'm making a christmas card with HTML I must use background image in order to avoid spam. However my background image does not appear in Outlook. Can you please fix this? P.S. I don`t know a thing about html I learn everything right now.

```
</table>

<table width="706" height="462" border="7"; bordercolor="#c89c53" align="center">


  <tr>
   <td background="http://ch-eu.com/dev/files/32.jpg" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="636" height="92" valign="top">


</table>
```

Comment: </table>

<table width="706" height="462" border="7"; bordercolor="#c89c53" align="center">


  <tr>
   <td background="http://ch-eu.com/dev/files/32.jpg" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="636" height="92" valign="top">
 
       
</table>

Comment: Looks like your url: "ch-eu.com/dev/files/32.jpg" is broken

Comment: Where is your </tr>

Comment: did you check to make sure that the link is not broken? did you check to make sure that in outlook, you allow the pictures to be loaded?

Comment: I don`t know why the link is not working here. It worked fine with me.

Comment: Where should I put other </tr> on which end? P.S. thank you for the help I really don`t know a thing